# Passing information from jQuery Function to Bootstrap Modal

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, flickr

I'm currently learning about Bootstrap Modal and API's.
Below is the code I currently have running as a learning exercise. You can view the page at http://jahax.com/ins/
It's basically a page that accesses the Flickr API through a jQuery Function then displays the pictures.

When I click an image, the Bootstrap Modal pops up but there is no website/image that comes up in it.

However, by clicking the 'click me' button at the bottom of the page, I can get the Bootstrap Modal to appear with a website in it.

Why can't I pass the information on from the jQuery Function to the Bootstrap Modal?
I have tried passing an image link and also a website through an Iframe.
Is there a way around this?

Thankyou in advance!

```
<div class="container">

    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Demonstration</h2>
    <p class="text-center">Demo of Bootstrap, jQuery & JSON API</p>
    <div class="row text-center">
    </div> 
    <div id="images" class="row text-center"> </div>

    <div class="row text-center">
    <a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-src="http://www.bing.com" data-height=640 data-width=800 data-target="#myModal">Click me</a>
    </div> 
</div>




<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="largeModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Demo of Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <iframe frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Start jQuery Function
    $(document).ready(function(){                   

        // JSON API to access Flickr               
        $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=winter&format=json&jsoncallback=?", displayImages);

        function displayImages(data) {                                                                                                                                 
            var iCount = 0;                             
            var htmlString = "<div class=row>";                 

            $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
                if (iCount < 18) {
                    var sourceSquare = (item.media.m).replace("_m.jpg", "_q.jpg");      

                    htmlString += '<a data-toggle="modal" class="btn" data-src="' + item.link + '" data-target="#myModal">';
                    htmlString += '<img src="' + sourceSquare + '" alt="' + item.title + '" title="' + item.title + '"/>';
                    htmlString += '</a>';
                }
                iCount++;
            });     

        // HTML into #images DIV
        $('#images').html(htmlString + "</div>");

        // Close down the JSON function call
        }

    // End jQuery function  
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Send Content to Bootstrap Modal
    $('a.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    var src = $(this).attr('data-src');
    var height = $(this).attr('data-height') || 300;
    var width = $(this).attr('data-width') || 400;

    $("#myModal iframe").attr({'src':src,
                           'height': height,
                           'width': width});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is because Flickr doesn't allow to embed withing frames. https://www.flickr.com/help/blogging/#1392237

Comment: Yes. However, even if i change it to youtube or bing or whatever it still does not pass it along.

Comment: You have added a Bing Link in the iframe on clicking on to the bottom button and it is working.
And also, youtube, provides their emebed code. you that code and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Iframe inside Modal Body and calling Flickr inside it.
The First thing is that you are using [Flickr](http://flickr.com/) Page Link and Flickr doesn't allow their webpages to open in IFrames.

You can Directly show your image on Modal window.

HTML Code :

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="largeModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Demo of Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img></img>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery Code :

```
$('a.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    var height = $(this).attr('data-height') || 300;
    var width = $(this).attr('data-width') || 400;

    $("#myModal .modal-body img").attr('src',src).css({
        height:height+'px',
        width:width+'px'
    });
});
```

Otherwise, if you want show the slideshow or other stuff from Flickr, then you need you use their API or third party Plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While this helps slightly. I am still unable to pass the information from the JSON API through to the Bootstrap Modal. I updated the site with your example. You can see what it has changed. The button works however when I click the flickr images I still get nothing.

Comment: I think the best way for me to ask how this is done is to say... "How can i make this page display a larger flickr photo when clicking the flickr photo that is shown?

Comment: You need to use the Flickr API for that. and try to get different size from flickr https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getSizes.html